# Cancel a future action

Tags: android

I am making a little game and in the game there is a random and a Media Player,

The random gives a number between 1-15 and then a CountDownTimer (the seconds of the countdown is the integrated random number), after the countdown is finished, the media player starts, here is my code:

```
final Random rand = new Random();
        time = rand.nextInt(15) + 1;
        new CountDownTimer(time * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                        R.raw.windows_8_notify);
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                mPlayer.start();
}
```

this code called when I press a button, is there anyway to cancel this action after the button pressed and before the mPlayer starts? what I mean is, when I release the button it will check if "Timecounter" equals to 0 and if it does, it will cancel the MediaPlayer before it starts, here is my release code:

```
    private View.OnTouchListener speakTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
        pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);
        if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                if (Timecounter == 0) {
                    textview.setText("You have released the button before the sound");
                    // ADD THE mPlayer cancel
                } else {
                    textview.setText("Your Reaction Time:" + Timecounter);
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    mPlayer.reset();
                }
                isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Sorry about my English :( hope you understand

**--EDIT--**

I have changed my code to:

```
private CountDownTimer CountDownTimer1;
....
final Random rand = new Random();
        time = rand.nextInt(15) + 1;
        final CountDownTimer CountDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(time * 1000,
                1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                        R.raw.windows_8_notify);
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                mPlayer.start();
                Timecounter = 0;
                Timer t = new Timer();
                TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Timecounter++;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
            }
        }.start();
        isSpeakButtonLongPressed = true;
        return true;
       ........
        if (Timecounter == 0) {
                    textview.setText("You have released the button before the sound");
                    CountDownTimer1.cancel();
                }
```

But it is not working, I get a nullpointerexception error at the logcat:
the error line is the timer cancel

```
    08-13 22:24:37.952: E/InputEventReceiver(1824): Exception dispatching input event.
08-13 22:24:37.952: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at com.time.reactiontime.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:83)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7708)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-13 22:24:37.967: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1824):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 22:24:37.967: D/AndroidRuntime(1824): Shutting down VM
08-13 22:24:37.967: W/dalvikvm(1824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41af3ce0)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824): Process: com.time.reactiontime, PID: 1824
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at com.time.reactiontime.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:83)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7708)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-13 22:24:37.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1824):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 22:24:39.788: I/Process(1824): Sending signal. PID: 1824 SIG: 9
08-13 22:27:10.452: D/OpenGLRenderer(1907): Enabling debug mode 0
08-13 22:27:10.545: I/ActivityManager(1907): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41daff28 time:246367862
08-13 22:27:12.741: E/InputEventReceiver(1907): Exception dispatching input event.
08-13 22:27:12.741: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at com.time.reactiontime.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:83)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7708)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-13 22:27:12.756: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1907):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 22:27:12.756: D/AndroidRuntime(1907): Shutting down VM
08-13 22:27:12.756: W/dalvikvm(1907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41af3ce0)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): Process: com.time.reactiontime, PID: 1907
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.time.reactiontime.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:83)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7708)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-13 22:27:12.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 2 ** 
CODE:

```
    package com.time.reactiontime;

import com.time.reactiontime.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.media.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int time;
    private int Timecounter = 0;
    private TextView textview;
    private Button button1;
    private boolean isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private CountDownTimer CountDownTimer1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        textview = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview));
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnLongClickListener(speakHoldListener);
        button1.setOnTouchListener(speakTouchListener);
    }

    private View.OnLongClickListener speakHoldListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View pView) {
            final Random rand = new Random();
            time = rand.nextInt(15) + 1;
            final CountDownTimer CountDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(
                    time * 1000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                            R.raw.windows_8_notify);
                    try {
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    mPlayer.start();
                    Timecounter = 0;
                    Timer t = new Timer();
                    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Timecounter++;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
                }
            }.start();
            isSpeakButtonLongPressed = true;
            return true;
        }
    };

    private View.OnTouchListener speakTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
            pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);
            if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                    if (Timecounter == 0) {
                        if (mPlayer == null) {

                        } else {
                            textview.setText("You have released the button before the sound");
                            CountDownTimer1.cancel();
                            mPlayer = null;
                        }
                    } else {
                        textview.setText("Your Reaction Time:" + Timecounter);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        mPlayer.reset();
                    }
                    isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Also, you should look at using `View.OnClickListener` instead of `View.OnTouchListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold on to a reference of the timer and call the [`cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()) method.

Edit based on Edit 2 of post

```
if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        textview.setText("You have released the button before the sound");
        CountDownTimer1.cancel();
    } else {
        textview.setText("Your Reaction Time:" + Timecounter);
        mPlayer.pause();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
    isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
}
```

Comment: If I will cancel the countdowntimer it will cancel the mediaPlayer?

Comment: Well the media player shouldn't have started before the `onFinish()` event fires. So if you cancel it before that's called (when time runs out) you should be good.

Comment: You never start your countdown timer, so I assume that's why you are recieving the NullPointerException, mPlayer is null. Is that suppose to start on `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: I don't know how your app is supposed to work. But my best guess would include a check to see if `mPlayer` is null, if it is, then you know `onFinish` hasn't been called yet and should say you pressed the button before the sound, else measure reaction time, reset `mPlayer` and set it back to null.

Comment: Ok so I added my code and here is what my app need to do: it have a button and a textview, when you long press the button it wait a random time and then plays a beep sound, when the beep sound starts you need to release the button (after the beep sound there is a timer who counts the time took to you to release it [reaction time]), now the problem is, when I long press and release before the sound, the timer doesn't stop, I still hear the beep after a few seconds..

Comment: You have logic issues. See the edit to my answer and change the portion inside of your `ACTION_UP` if to that. Also, look at the View.OnClickListener instead of using the on touch listener.